# Disable overflow mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the best way to disable overflow on mobile.
I already have overflow-x: hidden; on my body and seems to be fixed when I put the body to posistion: relative;
But then it messes up the rest of my website.

Kind regards,

```
body {
    font-family: 'Arial Regular';
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #131719;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Arial Regular';
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use CSS media queries for styles related to specific screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using media queries it is basically a way of saying in a specific size of a device how would certain elements look like. So what you can visit the link to find out more about media queries and I think it's fairly easy to use

[Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Hope this solution helps :)